# Elasticsearch Empty Filter Aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I upgraded `Elasticsearch` version `5.4` to `7.1`. I have a query work on `5.4` version, but the same query on `7.1` throws an exception.

> query malformed, empty clause found

Query :

```
{
    "query": {"match_all": {}}
    ,"aggs": {
       "price": {
           "aggs": {
              "tt": {
                  "terms": {
                     "field": "platformType"
                  }
              }
           },
           "filter": {

           }
       }
    }
}
```

The filter is empty because I use condition less term query. Is there any solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you expect with an empty filter section?

Comment: I dont expect anything in many case filter not empty like this                              {
    "query": {"match_all": {}}
    ,"aggs": {
       "price": {
           "aggs": {
              "tt": {
                  "terms": {
                     "field": "platformType"
                  }
              }
           },
           "filter": {
               "term": {
                  "isActive": "true"
               }
           }
       }
    }
}  ı put ın filter request data but ın some case data comes null

Comment: If you use the filter aggregation, you must always have something in it, math_all or anything

Comment: thank you @Val for your suggestion, I'll try it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Empty Clauses were deprecated](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17540). Use `match_all` just like you do in your `query` clause.

```
{
    "query": {"match_all": {}}
    ,"aggs": {
       "price": {
           "aggs": {
              "tt": {
                  "terms": {
                     "field": "platformType"
                  }
              }
           },
           "filter": {
                   "match_all": {}
           }
       }
    }
}
```